# Citext Data Type in Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: .net, wpf, postgresql, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I am developing a WPF desktop app with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 with code first from database approach.

The database is PostgreSQL and the data provider is EntityFramework6.Npgsql version 3.0.5.

My database contains multiple columns with citext data type such as the email as I want these columns to be unique and case insensitive.
The problem is when I try to add the data model in visual studio 2015  I get this warning

Error 6005: The data type 'citext' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version;

followed by too many errors, according to this link the citext data type was implemented back in version 3.0.1.

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Npgsql supports Citex data type at the **ADO.NET** layer but not in the Entity Framework 6 Layer.

So I ended up with two solutions.

1-Either change citex columns to text and use unique lower index on my case insensitive columns in the database and make all the queries from my application case insensitive.

2-Or keep citext type in the database and take previous auto generated model and
trick the Entity Framework (use string with citext properties).

Refer to this link for more details from the Npgsql development team.
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1029